# How can i do that in ASP.NET Web pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

in a tickets system..

lets say i have a combo-box where the user selects the **time of trip** and another combo-box where the user can select the **Trip id**.

what i'm trying to do is the make it so when he chooses the time the other "Trip id" combo box changes **automatically** to show all the trips available depending on the time he picked in the first combo-box.

so what i'm trying to do is a "**On-Change**" event or "**On-Click**" if it requires a button to be clicked

i'm using asp.net webpages with C# and razor

any idea ?

Comment: Could you describe more details? I cannot understand what you mean here. You have two combo boxes working with data of trip combo box depend on selected value of time combo box  but required a button clicked? What is button and its responsibilities at here?

Comment: forget that part, i meant a button to check, just like the "available" button beside the email text box when u register for an email and it checks whether its available or not.

Comment: OK. If you use javascript to handle event then on-change event is a good choice. If you use normally asp.net control the SelectedIndexChanged event should be used for this situation. Otherwise the ajax cascading control toolkit is a good choice as well, it will save your effort a lot.

Comment: @user2962142 - if you are using webpages, adding `webpages`, `webmatrix` tags will make easier to understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do that I think is to set js onchange event handler on the first select control and load items for the second one from server by HTTP GET request (using jquery f e). It is the most elegant, simple and lightweight solution.

**UPD:**
If you are familiar with js, you can return JSON array of trip ids from server and then create appropriate option element for each of them. If you don't, you can return from server the whole updated select control html and replace the existing one with it (it a little stupid approach, but a little easier).

In any case, the overall scheme is:
1. Create something on server side that could return json or html (Page that's Response content type is set to plain text f e or Service method) and accept one parameter — time from the first select.
2. On js handler of onchange event you make http get request to your page or service method (or controller action...):

```
function timeChanged () {
  $.getJSON(
    '/pageorsomethingelse.aspx?time=' + time,
    function (jsonResult) {
      $("#tripIdsSelect").html("");

      for (var i = 0; i != result.length; i++) {
        var option = $("<option>").html(result[i]);

        option.appendTo($("#tripIdsSelect"));
      }
    }
}
```

or

```
function timeChanged () {
  $.get(
    '/pageorsomethingelse.aspx?time=' + time,
    function (htmlResult) {
      $("#tripIdsSelect").replaceWith(htmlResult);
    }
  );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: could u please give more detials ? i made event handler but i cant realize how to load the other select control items from the database with javascript

Comment: @user2962142 I've updated the answer for u.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax toolkit [cascading dropdown list](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/cascadingdropdown/cascadingdropdown.aspx)

```
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CDD1" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="DropDownList2"
    Category="Model"
    PromptText="Please select a model"
    LoadingText="[Loading models...]"
    ServicePath="CarsService.asmx"
    ServiceMethod="GetDropDownContents"
    ParentControlID="DropDownList1"
    SelectedValue="SomeValue" />
```

**TargetControlID** - The ID of the DropDownList to populate.

**Category** - The name of the category this DropDownList represents.

**PromptText** - Optional text to display before the user has selected a value from the DropDownList.

**PromptValue** - Optional value set when PromptText is displayed.

**EmptyText** - Optional text to display when the DropDownList has no data to display.

**EmptyValue** - Optional value set when EmptyText is displayed.

**LoadingText** - Optional text to display while the data for the DropDownList is being 
loaded.

**ServicePath** - Path to a web service that returns the data used to populate the DropDownList. This property should be left null if ServiceMethod refers to a page method. The web service should be decorated with the System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService attribute.

**ServiceMethod** - Web service method that returns the data used to populate the DropDownList. The signature of this method must match the following:

Comment: i get unrecognized namespace "ajaxToolkit" error ,and where should i place the method that supposed to return the new values of second DropDownList ?